# Android Studio pref Editor.putString identifier expected

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

Getting a - cannot resolve symbol   "putString" "putInt" "commit" - in     the code below.Help please.

```
      public class Alpha extends Activity {

      public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
      SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

      SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
      prefEditor.putString("Gama x","Blue Spec");
      prefEditor.putInt("Wave",292);
      prefEditor.commit();


 }
```

Comment: move it inside onCreate. (`getSharedPreferences` as well)

Answer (score 1):

Before start coding randomly, have a look at some android tutorials for example [this is the best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAbQgLGKd3Y) **in my opinion**.

After you can start with coding.

btw the solution is moving it inside the "onCreate" method:

```
public class Alpha extends Activity {
  public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "GamePrefs";
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      SharedPreferences settings =getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFERENCES,MODE_PRIVATE);

      SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settings.edit();
      prefEditor.putString("Gama x","Blue Spec");
      prefEditor.putInt("Wave",292);
      prefEditor.commit();
  }
}
```